# Compare array attributes

Tags: php, arrays, comparison

I would like to compare two array items with php, I think I should use `array_intersect_key` but I don't know how I can do that.

Array 1

```
 [1] =&gt; obj Object
        (
            [idobj:protected] =&gt; 2
        )

 [2] =&gt; obj Object
        (
            [idobj:protected] =&gt; 1
        )
```

Array 2

```
 [1] =&gt; obj Object
        (
            [idobj:protected] =&gt; 1
        )
```

Comment: In what way do you want to compare the values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't need to use array_intersect_key() if you need only to compare array elements.

It simple like this (for two-dimensional arrays):

```
if( $array1[0] == $array2[0] ) {
  echo 'Array items are equal';
} else {
  echo 'Array items are not equal';
}
```

If you have multi-dimensional array you may need add some extra indexes.

PHP manual has a very good information regarding arrays, [check it out](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

Answer (score 0):

Are you actually looking for [`array_intersect()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php)?

```
$objectsInArray1ThatArePresentInArray2 = array_intersect($array1, $array2);
```